# populate some of the rows in a data frame using the other column

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I am trying to populate column `size` where its value is 0. The new value should be the last segment of column `name`. I have tried many methods, but somehow when I am trying to populate only rows with 0 it does not return the correct values:

**sample data:**

```
vertices=data.frame(name=c("a","b","c","a.b","a.c","a.a.9","a.b.8"),size= c(1,5,6,2,6,0,0))

ID name size
1     a    1
2     b    5
3     c    6
4   a.b    2
5   a.c    6
6 a.a.9    0
7 a.b.8    0
```

This line works as expected, except I don't want to touch the rows that are not size=0:

```
vertices$size <- sub(".*\\.", "", vertices$name)

ID name size
1     a    a
2     b    b
3     c    c
4   a.b    b
5   a.c    c
6 a.a.9    9
7 a.b.8    8
```

And when adding the condition to the code, it returns wrong results:

```
vertices$size[vertices$size==0] <- sub(".*\\.", "", vertices$name)

ID name size
1     a    1
2     b    5
3     c    6
4   a.b    2
5   a.c    6
6 a.a.9    a
7 a.b.8    b
```

The last 2 rows should be 9 and 8. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to subset even the `name`

```
vertices$size[vertices$size==0]<- sub(".*\\.", "", vertices$name[vertices$size==0])

vertices
#   name size
#1     a    1
#2     b    5
#3     c    6
#4   a.b    2
#5   a.c    6
#6 a.a.9    9
#7 a.b.8    8
```

---

Or you can also use an `ifelse` with same effect

```
vertices$size <- ifelse(vertices$size == 0, sub(".*\\.", "", vertices$name), 
                                            vertices$name)
```

As @Frank mentioned in comments `size` changes it's class from numeric to character because of regex approach.

```
sub(".*\\.", "", vertices$name[vertices$size==0])
#[1] "9" "8"
```

If we need to maintain the class of the `size` column we can use `as.numeric`.

```
as.numeric(sub(".*\\.", "", vertices$name[vertices$size==0]))
#[1] 9 8
```

However, this is again assuming that where `size = 0` the last character is a number , if it is a character it would return `NA`.

Comment: If you decided post it as an answer , How about delete it from the comment

Comment: `size` starts out numeric and is coerced to string here, I guess. Another good reason to use data.table, which would warn and then coerce character to numeric instead of the other way around...

Comment: @Frank Using regex does that. We can always wrap it with `as.numeric` to maintain the class. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to save a vector of the wrong size. In the last line you probably just want

```
vertices$size[vertices$size==0] <- sub(".*\\.", "", vertices$name[vertices$size==0])
```

You're missing the condition on the RHS.

You get "a" and "b" in those last two position as it is just taking the first two elements of the vector (which in your case is the sub on all the names).

Answer (score 1):

With `stringr` and `dplyr`

```
vertices %>% mutate(size = ifelse(size > 0, size, str_extract(name, "[0-9]+")))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could also use `regmatches/regexpr`

```
vertices$size[!vertices$size] <- 
    as.numeric(regmatches(vertices$name, regexpr("\\d+$", vertices$name)))

vertices
#   name size
#1     a    1
#2     b    5
#3     c    6
#4   a.b    2
#5   a.c    6
#6 a.a.9    9
#7 a.b.8    8
```